# Is there another way to get website working when getting HTTP Error 404.7 Not found?

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, coldfusion-11

I have upgraded from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 11.  Installation is a side-by-side, internal webserver.  After the migration I ran the wsconfig to connect my 4 websites to IIS.  Websites don't work and I get the `HTTP Error 404.7 Not found`. The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension?  I've created a test website with two simple Hello World files in it, one html and the other cfm.  html works and the only way I can get the cfm file to work and not get this message is to go into IIS, click on my TEST website, Request Filtering, Edit Feature Settings, and check on Allow unlisted file name extensions.  As I understand it this basically allows anything to be processed.  That is not going to be an option with our hyper secure websites.

Two questions come to mind:

1. Why should I have to do this after the upgrade when before the websites worked just fine?  My cfm pages should process without altering this IIS setting.  Nothing in IIS shows that any ColdFusion extension is set to deny.  Nothing in applicationhost.config or web.config show any ColdFusion extension set to deny.
2. Why won't my web pages work period?  I can't get past the configuration.cfc that points to a configuration.cfm file that checks the user, server to give the user access to the proper pages.  Obviously there is a configuration that is different in ColdFusion 11 vs ColdFusion 9, but I can't find it.  All my error messages point to IIS being the source of the issues and I haven't changed that, beyond the wsconfig file creating a different web.config file when the connection was created.

I'm starting to pour through all and any log files that are created to put anything creating at the running of the cfm page into a document to see if I can find anything that can tell me what is happening.  My team lead thinks I need to look at perhaps there might be an external/internal Tomcat conflict going on that is preventing the pages from processing.

The exact error message today is:

> Error Summary
>   HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
>   The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.
>
> Detailed Error Information
>   Module     RequestFilteringModule
>   Notification     BeginRequest
>   Handler     ISAPI-dll
>   Error Code     0x00000000
>   Requested URL     http://{ipaddress}/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll
>   Physical Path     D:\ColdFusion11\config\wsconfig\5\isapi_redirect.dll
>   Logon Method     Not yet determined
>   Logon User     Not yet determined
>
> Most likely causes:
>   Request filtering is configured for the Web server and the file extension for this request is explicitly denied
>
> Things you can try:
>   Verify the configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/fileExtensions settings in applicationhost.config and web.config.

Comment: Are you using the latest ColdFusion 11 installation files? There have been several issues with ColdFusion 11 and several updates have been released. Make sure you are using the latest [ColdFusion Update 3](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-11-update-3.html) - released December 9, 2014.

Comment: I didn't think Update 3 was official.  I have Update 2 installed successfully. What do you know?  http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-11-update-3.html  I'll have to download the jar file and install it.  Our server isn't connected to the real world. :)

Comment: I'll respond further when I've reinstalled CF11 and applied Update 3.  Right now researching logs need to make verbose before installation.  Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean for the web server connector? [How to enable verbose logging at connector level in ColdFusion](https://nimitsharma.wordpress.com/2014/09/23/how-to-enable-verbose-logging-at-connector-level-in-coldfusion/)